# psql create CSV with comma,quote and pipe as part of data

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy, delimiter, psql

I am trying to create a CSV from table data.

```
      column1                      column2
this,is"part|of"the,:long,//data  :"hello,
```

Expected output:

```
column1,column2
this\,is"part|of"the\,:long\,//data,:"hello\,
```

My end goal is to load this CSV delimited by ',' into a hive table

i tried this but didn't work:

```
\COPY (select * from table) TO /tmp/file.csv WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', ESCAPE '\', HEADER TRUE);

CSV i got:
column1,column2
this,is"part|of"the,:long,//data,:"hello,
```

The commas weren't prefixed by backslash.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "didn't work".

Comment: Done. Edited the question

Comment: Commas should not be escaped because the whole values are enclosed by double quotes: `copy (select 'this,is"part|of"the,:long,//data' as x, ':"hello,' as y) to stdout WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', ESCAPE '\', HEADER TRUE);` and result: `"this,is\"part|of\"the,:long,//data",":\"hello,"`

Comment: That's invalid CSV data in the original question, embedded double quotes are not escaped

Comment: @Abelisto Thank you.
CraigRinger Double quotes are allowed to be part of data in postgres